# Save class flextable element into pdf

Tags: r, pdf, save, pdf-generation, flextable

I would like to save ftmax and ftmin as pdf, how can I do it?

```
ftmax <- tablemax %>% head() %>% as.data.frame() %>% add_rownames("Stock") %>% flextable()
ftmin <- tablemin %>% head() %>% as.data.frame() %>% add_rownames("Stock") %>% flextable()

ftmax <- set_caption(ftmax, "Greatest positive deviation from distribution")
ftmin <- set_caption(ftmin, "Greatest negative deviation from distribution")

ftmax <- autofit(ftmax)
ftmin <- autofit(ftmin)

ftmax
ftmin
```

No rmarkdown, thank you!

An alternative way to plot a df nicely is otherwise appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `save_as_image` with extension ".pdf" like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(webshot)
ftmax <- mtcars %>% head() %>% as.data.frame() %>% add_rownames("Stock") %>% flextable()
#> Warning: `add_rownames()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.0.0.
#> Please use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
ftmin <- mtcars %>% head() %>% as.data.frame() %>% add_rownames("Stock") %>% flextable()

ftmax <- set_caption(ftmax, "Greatest positive deviation from distribution")
ftmin <- set_caption(ftmin, "Greatest negative deviation from distribution")

ftmax <- autofit(ftmax)
ftmin <- autofit(ftmin)

save_as_image(x = ftmax, path = "ftmax.pdf")
save_as_image(x = ftmin, path = "ftmin.pdf")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here is the output of `ftmax`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The output table however is really small in the pdf, could you please tell me the parameters to settle inside the save_as_image function? @Quinten

Comment: Zoom = 0.5 and Expand = 5000 works well, thank you!